# server side pagination doesn't seem to be working c# asp.net jquery datatables

Tags: c#, pagination, datatables

I am trying to get the pagination to work but it's not working. I have over 90k records in the database but it only displays 50 records as per in the screen shot below:

[image]

I am returning the below JSON as per [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part) and this [resolved query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535167/jquery-datatables-net-server-side-pagination-issues):

```
return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = tracks.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredTracks.Count(),
            aaData = results
        },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is the pagination Controller code:

```
var displayedTracks = filteredTracks.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
```

Here's my `View` code of the dataTable:

```
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').hide(50).fadeIn(10).dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": " "
        },
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "sAjaxSource": "Ajax_DB",
        "deferRender": false,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sScrollY": "333",
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
    { "mDataProp_": "TrackID", "sWidth": "1%" },
    { "mDataProp_": "AddedDate", "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "1%" },
    { "mDataProp_": "TrackName", "sWidth": "43%" },
    { "mDataProp_": "ArtistName", "sWidth": "30%" },
    { "mDataProp_": "ArtistName", "sWidth": "30%" }
        ]
    });
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here, the pagination doesn't seem to work. Could someone please help me on how I can achive this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple mate

Just change your **iDisplayLength** property's  value to your required count i.e 100 or what ever

```
"iDisplayLength": 100
```

Refer [datatables.net](http://datatables.net) for documentaions which which will help you

Hope it helps

Have you sure your code looks like this :

```
 filteredLeads = filteredLeads.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);

 var DisplayedLeads = filteredLeads.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);

            var result = from c in DisplayedLeads select new string[] { // my columns  };
            return Json(new
            {
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = leadDetails.Count(),
                iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredLeads.Count(),
                aaData = result
            },
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Let know what is your test results appearing at itotalrecords,iTotalDisplayRecords, aaData while debugging .

Comment: thanks, I tried mostly everything. It doesn't matter what count you put in on `iDisplayLength`. `iDisplayLength` shows the # of records per page you want to show. The issue here is that it is not showing `Pagination`. I have 90k records on server-side, so I can't put 90,000 in `iDisplayLength` hence the `pagination` is required to show 50 / 100 records per page. thank again :)

Comment: ok i tought the other way my bad . let me know further . check the edit

Comment: it's cool you were just trying to help :) I tried what you suggested but it is still giving me the results as previous to what I had. I have updated my full controller code for your detailed inspection. Everything works in it i.e. Search, dates, sorting apart from pagination. thanks again :)

Comment: well by look of it i find no issues particularly. As per your sample image display its like **1-50** . Are you sure `iTotalRecords = tracks.Count()` is not 50 ? data-tables are too sensitive and hard to find out exact root cause until one personally debug it . `.hide(50).fadeIn(10)` are you sure this wont effect ? i never used that . cheers

Comment: well let me know if you keep `idisplaylength:100` you getting something like 1-100 or else 1-50 only ? Datatable.js version ? `iTotalRecords = 90000 ,iTotalDisplayRecords = 50` you getting like this debug and let me know .