# Not able to paginate in Angularjs Datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I am using [angularjs + datatable plugin](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) . But for some reason it is not giving me any option to click next pages (the page number that appear at the bottom 1 2 3 ....).
[image]

In the image which is the footer of the table, there are total 22 records and 10 are being displayed but the number 2 is not displayed for the subsequent page in the footer.

Following is controller code.

```
angular.module('tableTest', ['datatables']).controller('TableCtrl',function ($scope,$compile,DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
var vm = this;
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax', {
     url: '/tableDatalist',
     type: 'GET'
 })
 .withDataProp('data')
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex) {
        $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    })
    .withOption('responsive', true)
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
vm.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('group').withTitle('Group').withOption('bSortable',true),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('startTime').withTitle('Start').withOption('bSortable',true),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('endTime').withTitle('End').withOption('bSortable',true),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('status').withTitle('Status').withOption('bSortable',true),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('reason').withTitle('Reason').withOption('bSortable',true),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('transactionGroup').withTitle('Transaction Group').withOption('bSortable',true),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('geoGroup').withTitle('Geo Group').withOption('bSortable',true),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('group').withTitle('Current Status').renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
        var arr = full.endTime.split(/-|\s|:/);
        var endTime = new Date(arr[0], parseInt(arr[1])-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
        arr = full.startTime.split(/-|\s|:/);
        var startTime = new Date(arr[0], parseInt(arr[1])-1, arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]);
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var color = ['#2196F3','#009688'];
        var currentStatus = ['INACTIVE','ACTIVE']
        var index;
        if(startTime.getTime() <= currentTime.getTime() && currentTime.getTime() <= endTime.getTime()) {
            index = 1;
        } else {
            index = 0;
        }
        return '<span style="background : '+color[index]+';color: #FFF;font-weight: 500;" class="currentStatus"> &nbsp;&nbsp;'+currentStatus[index]+'&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>';
    }).notSortable(),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('code').withTitle('Select').notSortable().renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<span class="code"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="_'+data+'" ng-change="toggleExistingTransactionSelection('+data+',_'+data+')"></span>';
    })
]; 
});
```

following is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TableCtrl as showCase">
                        <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table>
                    </div>
```

Server Side code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "//tableDatalist", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getTransactionGroupList(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    try {
        // some logic...
        resource.put("data", rows).put("recordsTotal",page.getTotalElements()).put("recordsFiltered", rows.length()).put("draw", httpRequest.getParameter("draw"));
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(resource.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error while getting allowed resources : ", e);
        ErrorResponse er = new ErrorResponse().serverError().setMsg("........");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(er.toJson(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Following is the [link](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for what is sent and received from server.

I don't understand why it is not showing the page 2 in the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535167/jquery-datatables-net-server-side-pagination-issues#answer-7549072).

> Your `recordsFiltered` is equal to 10, so datatables think that there are only 10 records on the server side and second page is not needed because all of them are already shown on the current page. This is comon mistake.