# How pagination works in Angular datatables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, pagination

I am using [Angular datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) to implement pagination and sorting in my project work. I have a RESTful webservice that returns be a JSON array, like for example

```
[{"name":"abc", "id", "4"},{"name":"abc2", "id", "5"},{"name":"abc3", "id", "6"}, .....]
```

I tried to refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535167/jquery-datatables-net-server-side-pagination-issues) for Jquery datatables. The problem described over there is the same for me but I need to do using angular datatables

In the webservice response i get the above data and also parameters for Page Count and Page size. Page size is 10 (only 10 records come from database) and Page count is the number of records to be displayed.

I get page size as 10 and page count is 15.

However my datatable just shows me page 1 in the pagination below and does not page 2.

Is there an equivalent for [iTotalDisplayRecords](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) as in Jquery datatables for Angular JS as well. I couldn't find a similar parameter in the documentation.

Can someone please help?

Comment: how does your code looks like - how do you initialise angular-datatables?